# How to use ApolloClient Mutation with consequent api calls with business logic in between?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

The way its built today,  is necessarily bound to a server api GraphQL schema, meaning - if you use  it necessarily runs single unit of logic IN THE SERVER.

My problems with this is that in client side code, sometimes I want to run multiple different updates / creates in a single unit of logic IN THE CLIENT and bind my  to that.

For example, lets examine the following facebook connect flow and load facebook pages:

User is redirected to facebook connect
After logging in, user redirected back to the app (React based website), and the state of the page turns to Loading
Then, an API call to facebook/me/accounts is made in order to load the pages from Facebook
Then, a call to save all pages in the database is called
Then, another 3rd party API is called;
Then, the state of the page turns to ready and the User's facebook pages are loaded from the server API and displayed on the pages using .
In this case, steps 3, 4, 5 are not changing the client app state, however, if Implemented using  it requires me to create a different state in the UI in order to execute each step separately.

If I could connect Mutation object to a local API or a local function, this would have definitely solved it for me since I would have been able to run 3,4,5 steps sequentially together without changing client state.

What is the best way to approach this scenario using Mutations?
Is there anything I am missing with how I'm supposed to use Mutations with Apollo?

Comment: you can use apollo for local state (one mutation) using client-side resolver (multi step logic) ... but probably better would be server side graphql on top of other services - schema stiching, etc.

Comment: There is logic in between calls, will schema stiching still work? and what if I have client side 3rd party api calls like analytics etc...

Comment: Client side resolver sounds like a very complex solution for what should be a simple problem since It would require you do also define a schema for the client side, right?